# How do I move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character?

Tags: indentation, cursor-movement

In a very long file with (accurately-) indented code, it may be helpful to move directly to a line of text above or below the cursor which delimits the indenting.

(One way of doing this could be via the indent foldmethod, by folding the current indent level, which collapses the lines delimiting the indent level to be only a `j` or `k` away from the cursor. However, I have found instances where indent folding hasn't been able to work on the indent I'm interested in.)

Here's an example, with the cursor marked by the underscore `_` (at the second character column between the definitions of `class Bazz` and `class Qux`), but imagine that the number of paragraphs or lines within the `module`s is unknown or variable:

```
module Foo
  # lots of code...
end

module Bar
  class Baz
    # ...
  end

  class Bazz
    # lots of code...
  end
 _
  class Qux
    # ...
  end

  class Quux
    # lots of code...
  end
end
```

...how could I quickly navigate to the `o` of `module Bar` above the cursor, or the `n` of the `end` below the cursor at the very last line? Note that the vertical column contains whitespaces, but also no characters at the second column in between the `class` definitions.

Comment: related: "Move to next/previous line with same indentation " on Vim Tips Wiki http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_to_next/previous_line_with_same_indentation

Comment: Pressing g and then direction key might avoid tabs and move across lines

Comment: The solution in @alxndr's link works well except in the case where the whitespace is poorly maintained (e.g., there are random lines that only have whitespaces) and you want to ignore the whitespace.  superjer's solution below is better if one is concerned about that case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this function?

```
function FloatUp()
    while line(".") > 1
                \ && (strlen(getline(".")) < col(".")
                \ || getline(".")[col(".") - 1] =~ '\s')
        norm k
    endwhile
endfunction
```

You could `nnoremap gU :call FloatUp()<CR>` (`gU` for "go up"), and then invoke with `gU`.

Here's an explanation:

- The code repeatedly moves up the cursor (with `norm k`) as long as the `while` condition holds.
- The `while` condition holds if this is not the first line (`line(".") > 1`) and either

  - this line is too short (probably empty); or
  - the current line (`getline(".")`)'s character at the current column (`[col(".") - 1]`) is whitespace (`=~ '\s'`; i.e., matches the whitespace pattern).

Comment: This seems to work perfectly (and quickly), and is easily modified into a `FloatDown` function as well. Into my .vimrc it goes, thanks! https://github.com/alxndr/dotfiles/commit/0e25a302

Comment: Just discovered that this solution doesn't quite work in visual mode (slightly different behavior depending on which visual mode, it'll either stay in the same position or move by only one line). Any pointers on what's going on there?

Comment: I've packaged this up into my Lua config: this function (and corresponding `FloatDown`) wrapped in `vim.cmd [[ .. ]]` defined in one file https://github.com/alxndr/dotfiles/blob/bf37c21/nvim/lua/plugin/vertical_space_jumper.lua and required via `init.lua`, and then those functions are mapped with `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap()` like so https://github.com/alxndr/dotfiles/blob/bf37c21/nvim/lua/mappings.lua#L21-L22

Answer (score 18):

I like using search for these things, because Vim's regexs have an insane amount of things you can search for, like specific virtual column numbers, in this case:

`nnoremap cd /\%<C-R>=virtcol(".")<CR>v\S<CR>`

`nnoremap cu ?\%<C-R>=virtcol(".")<CR>v\S<CR>`

Use `cd` to go down and `cu` to go up. I'm thinking "column up" and "column down" here. I'm almost 100% confident that these are no-ops by default. Or pick your own mappings.

This should work whether you are using tabs or spaces or both.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing those commands. Would you mind expanding on them a bit?

Comment: / or ? to search down or up, \%xv limits to search to virtual column number 'x', the 'x' in this case is '<C-R>=virtcol(".")<CR>' which runs the virtcol command and inserts the virtual column number the cursor is at into the expression, \S means any non-whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Chad. I will just add that <C-R> in Insert mode or Command-line mode grabs the contents of a register. The `=` register is the expression register which evaluates an expression in place. It's very handy, if not a bit weird looking.

Comment: Wow, that's an amazing use of search, thanks @superjer! And my mind is blown for the day by learning about vim's advanced registers.

Comment: One disadvantage of this approach is that if you have search highlighting on, you'll find that all the characters in the cursor's vertical column are now highlighted after "column up"ing or "column down"ing.

Comment: @alxndr then add `:let @/=""<C-R>` to clear the last search.

Comment: It would also be nice to avoid modifying the search at all, in case I already have something highlighted which I'd like to keep highlighted... But I suppose that's the price of using the search feature.

Comment: If you want to protect your existing search you can prepend `:let searchbak=@/<CR>` and append `:let @/=searchbak<CR>`. But at this point it's getting kind of long and unapproachable and maybe should just be a function.

Comment: kenorb's solution (under 'don't want to use plugins') has those advantages and also doesn't mess with highlighting as @alxndr requested - simply use the `search()` function instead of actually searching in normal mode.

Answer (score 9):

You may use [JumpToVerticalOccurrence](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4841) plugin (default mapped to <kbd>]|</kbd> and <kbd>[|</kbd>). There are few others like <kbd>]V{char}</kbd> which works like <kbd>f</kbd>, but vertically. You can of course remap them as required.

---

If you don't want to use plugins, you may try to use `:search` with `virtcol(.)`, e.g.:

```
:call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'bW')
```

where:

- `virtcol('.')` gives you the current column,
- `\S` stands for non-whitespace
- `bW` is for backward search

Check `:help search` to learn more.

To make it easier to use, you can map it, e.g.:

```
:map <C-k> :call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'bW')<CR>
:map <C-j> :call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'W')<CR>
```

---

Alternatively, if your code contains brackets, use <kbd>%</kbd> to jump between matching them (e.g. `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, etc.) or use whole paragraph jumps (<kbd>{</kbd>, <kbd>}</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd> if necessary).

---

Links/sources:

- [Move to the next row which has non-white space character in the same column in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882722/move-to-the-next-row-which-has-non-white-space-character-in-the-same-column-in-v) at stackoverflow

Comment: From [`:h search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29): `w` means `wrap around the end of the file` and `W` means `don't wrap around the end of the file`. But why did you put them together on the second `:map`?

Comment: @JairLopez Correct, `w` shouldn't be there, so I've removed it, thanks. Probably I was confused by motion keys meaning.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Wrapped in Lua for Neovim: https://github.com/alxndr/dotfiles/blob/15d7c0f/nvim/lua/plugin/vertical_space_jumper.lua

Answer (score 3):

I use a modified version of the [vim-indent-object](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) plugin to provide this behavior.  My modifications can be seen [here](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-indent-object/blob/working/plugin/indentobject.vim).

This allows me to map `[i` to go to beginning of current indent level and `]i` to go the end.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't see it here as an answer (**edit** just noticed that **superjer** mentioned something very similar). You can simply the / or ? search.

For example, you can search downward for a non whitespace character in the 2nd column like this:

```
/\%2v\S
```

The breakdown is:

```
/    "search downward (use ? for upward movement)
\%2v "for the following char in the 2nd virtual column
\S   "any non white space character
```

Then you can use the normal operators to repeat the search.

For more info on the subject see `:help \%c` and `:help \%v`.

Comment: Oh my god, literally the last answer on the page and it's the one that best answers the question.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you asked for because it's not vertical movement,
but something that's similar, fast, and might be good enough for you is moving backward 2 paragraphs: <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>. This will take you to the line right before `module Bar`.

Comment: Imagine there are an unknown number of lines and/or paragraphs between the cursor and its top-level `module` line. (Specifically, this situation arose when I was recently navigating third-party code several thousand lines long, with accurate indentation but no empty lines, and trying to find the outer context of a module's definition.)

Comment: Jumping by paragraphs is my preferred way of moving around, but it wasn't an option: the entire file was one "paragraph".

Answer (score 2):

[jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise) works well for relative, absolute, or block-scope movements across indented blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own plugin [move_until_char_changes.vim](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/plugin/move_until_char_changes.vim) for that.

I map it to `gK` and `gJ`.

It will jump over many lines with the same character in the current column (not just whitespace), which can be useful in logfiles or SQL dumps with repeated strings.

By default it first moves one line, before picking up the "search" character.

It works in Visual mode provided you don't try to use it twice, and you aren't in linewise or blockwise Visual mode... (fixes welcome!)