# How do I search for a line that contains a pattern at column n

Tags: vimscript, search, regular-expression

In writing some Vimscript to try to answer [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/145/182), I was exploring ways to "search for a line with pattern P in position X" (P is a search pattern, X is a number).

One way to do this would be to search for (e.g.) `^.....[a-z]`, where `[a-z]` is the pattern, and `5` is the position.

But how would I use Vimscript to make `.....`, from `.` and `5`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use regex syntax for "repeat `n` times":

```
/^.\{5}[a-z]
```

This searches for 5 `.`s and then an `[a-z]`.

If you just want to repeat a character `c` `n` times, simply do:

```
let dots = repeat('.', 5)
" dots is now '.....'
```

Comment: That'll work for my example, but I was hoping for a more general answer which could be used in other kinds of string building

Comment: @jalanb You could use `repeat`; see my edit.

Answer (score 5):

Vim also has this nice feature `/\%5c[a-z]` which matches `[a-z]` only in column 5. You can read about it in more detail in [`:h \%c`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5c%25c). There is also [`\%v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5c%25v) which is to be used for virtual column which is relevant in case of a lot of wrapped lines and it will match the virtual column even for the wrapped lines.