# Motion to jump back one level of indentation, not including blank lines

Tags: indentation, cursor-motions, visual-mode, normal-mode

I've been authoring a lot of F# in Vim lately. Like Python it is pretty strictly indentation-based. However, unlike [Python mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) for Vim, it does not appear that the standard [F# Vim plugin](https://github.com/fsharp/vim-fsharp) supports any kinds of motions. I would like the ability to rapidly navigate over modules and functions, in the spirit of what is done with [motions for classes and functions](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/develop/doc/pymode.txt#L165) in Python mode:

> ```
> [M      Jump to previous class or method (normal, visual, operator modes)
> ]M      Jump to next class or method (normal, visual, operator modes)
> aC      Select a class. Ex: vaC, daC, yaC, caC (normal, operator modes)
> iC      Select inner class. Ex: viC, diC, yiC, ciC (normal, operator modes)
> aM      Select a function or method. Ex: vaM, daM, yaM, caM (normal, operator modes)
> iM      Select inner function or method. Ex: viM, diM, yiM, ciM (normal, operator modes)
> ```

So specifically, given some code like this:

```
module Foobar =
    let private foo'() =
        bar'()
        |> baz'()
        |> qux'()

    let foo() =
        bar()
        |> baz()
        |> qux()
```

I would like to be able to quick jump to the beginning and end of functions and modules.

I can write some code to do this based on Python mode, but before jumping to that I was wondering, since Vim comes with so many motions built in, **Is there a way to say, "move to the first place where there is a nonblank line that is set back *n* indentation levels from current line"?**

I have not been able to find anything, maybe because Vim was built originally more for C-style code, but I wanted to know if there was any existing functionality (or existing plugin for that matter) that handled this case, because if so that would probably take care of 95% of what I need without having to implement the motions for F#-specific semantics.

Comment: how about directly using vim's builtin powerful regex search?

Comment: have you tried EasyMotion? https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Plugin [indentwise](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise) by jeetsukumaran

#### Movements by Relative Indent-Depth

- `[-`  : Move to *previous* line of *lesser* indent than the current line.
- `[+`  : Move to *previous* line of *greater* indent than the current line.
- `[=`  : Move to *previous* line of *same* indent as the current line that
        is separated from the current line by lines of different indents.
- `]-`  : Move to *next* line of *lesser* indent than the current line.
- `]+`  : Move to *next* line of *greater* indent than the current line.
- `]=`  : Move to *next* line of *same* indent as the current line that
        is separated from the current line by lines of different indents.

#### Movements by Absolute Indent-Levels

- `{count}[_`  : Move to *previous* line with indent-level of `{count}`.
- `{count}]_`  : Move to *next* line with indent-level of `{count}`.

#### Movements by Indent-Block Scope

- `[%`  : Move to beginning of indent-block scope (i.e., move to the
        line just after the previous line of lesser indent); repeat
        for `{count}` outer scopes.
- `]%`  : Move to end of indent-block scope (i.e., move to the line
        just before the next line of lesser indent); repeat
        for `{count}` outer scopes.

  If you use [matchit's](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit) ([matchup](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup)) `[%` and `]%`, you have to pick different ones ([#issue 6](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise/issues/6)).

#### Remarks

- This question is possibly a duplicate of [How do I move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-do-i-move-vertically-until-reaching-a-non-whitespace-character)
  similar as the question [Structural navigation by indentation level](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8719/structural-navigation-by-indentation-level).
  However, I would like to emphasize that the idea is about navigating based on different indentation levels which is not the focus of the title [How do I move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-do-i-move-vertically-until-reaching-a-non-whitespace-character).
- see also wiki page ['Move to next/previous line with same indentation'](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_to_next/previous_line_with_same_indentation)

Futher related plugins are

- [tmhedberg/indent-motion](https://github.com/tmhedberg/indent-motion)
- [inkarkat/vim-JumpToVerticalOccurrence](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-JumpToVerticalOccurrence)
- [michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object)
- [qstrahl/vim-dentures](https://github.com/qstrahl/vim-dentures)