# Structural navigation by indentation level

Tags: indentation

Suppose I have a pretty-printed JSON file that I'm trying to navigate and my cursor is at the `X` position. Is there a motion to move to the nearest line above/below the current one with an indentation level less than or equal to my cursor's current location?

```
{
    "foo": [
        <object>,
        <object>,
        <object>,
     X  ...,
        <object>
    ]
}
```

When I go "up" I'd like to jump to the `"foo": [` line.

Comment: Question seems similar to http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/120/67