# Column-based w command?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

From a given cursor position, how can I move *vertically* to the next non-whitespace character (in the same column), whether up or down?

Since I highly doubt this is a built-in motion command (if it is then great!), how can I map Ctrl-K and Ctrl-J to do this?

(This is inspired by the Excel feature, oddly enough.)

---

For a bonus: Make g followed by Ctrl-K and Ctrl-J work on soft-wrapped columns.  Far less critical but it would be cool.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-do-i-move-vertically-until-reaching-a-non-whitespace-character?

Comment: Do you want the cursor to skip past the *current* vertical "word", like the `w` motion (as implied by your title)? If so then this isn't a duplicate of the question muru links to (although it's obviously closely related), but I think you could clarify this in the question body.

Comment: @Rich good question.  Yes, if currently on non whitespace I want to go *past* the next batch of white/empty columns to start of next "word," exactly like w command and b.

Comment: Hmm, missed the link before, this does look like a duplicate to me. How is this different from the linked question?